# Opencart change the code of installed extension

Tags: php, html, opencart

I have recently installed an extension which goal is to put the "home link" in the header menu navigation.

The extension was installed through ocmod. The code of the extension:

```
<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search ><![CDATA[<ul class="nav navbar-nav">]]></search>
        <add position="after"><![CDATA[<li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

I would like to change the string inside `<li></li>` into an icon instead of text.

Change this:

```
<add position="after"><![CDATA[<li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>]]></add>
```

Into this:

```
<add position="after"><![CDATA[<li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>]]></add>
```

I have searched everywhere and I found in the database there's a table called `oc_modification` which contains the code of the plugin. I have changed and updated that row to fill my interests but I see no modification on my website.

[image]

How do I change the code of an installed extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

I had to clear the cache through the menu `Extensions > Modifications`.